# Unable to change in stock text for products in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

This is quite a weird one...

At some point previously, we had changed the default 'In Stock' text to 'Available to order' on products in Magento.

Default:-
    Availability: In Stock

New:-
    Availability: Available to order

The thing is, we can't find where or how this is being overridden...

In the below file, the default stock messages In Stock and Out of Stock still remain. If I display template hints with block names on the front end, the block points to this file. If I change the text 'In Stock' in this file, it does change the text 'Available to order' on the front end.

```
/app/design/frontend/*/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml
```

There are no CSS / JS text replaces for this and there are no language files edited to change the text 'In Stock' to 'Available to order'.

In fact, I have done a site search on the entire contents of the /app directory on the server and there is no results found for 'Available to order' in any file.

All cache has been cleared (including cache storage), and full reindex has been performed.

All I'm trying to achieve, is to change it back to 'In Stock' from 'Available to order' but as per the template file, it is already set to 'In Stock'.

Fast running out of ideas on this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what was controlling this in the core_translate table in the database.

All this table contained was the below...

[image]

Exactly what was overriding the default 'In Stock' label.

Looks like inline translation from the Magento back office was used at some point to set this.

Thanks to Mufaddal for [answering](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3381/798) this one.